# click on div[contenteditable] if last element is span[contenteditable="false"]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If click on the `div` after all text, the `div` is focused but the caret is not set (the caret set in `span.notContentEditable` and not shown) ( problem exist in firefox/vivaldi/(chrome on ubuntu 19.10) )

```css
div[name="comment"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font: medium -moz-fixed;
  font: -webkit-small-control;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: both;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div name="comment" contenteditable="true">
  <span class="bold" contenteditable="false">spantext</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what your issue is. The only thing I can see is that if you click on `spantext` the caret doesn't appear, but this is expected behaviour as the span is not editable

Comment: if click on div( after text ), required what caret setting after span

Comment: Sorry, again that doesn't make any sense

Comment: Please learn to articulate a real questions and then come back. Just stating your issue not indicating the expected result is the recipe for getting irrelevant answers.

Comment: That's an FF only(?) issue, that's why most of you don't understand. In that browser, there is simply no way to enter the editable zone of the parent element, even though it has contenteditable. Though I'm pretty sure I saw a dupe somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

This is not clear what you ask, but if you want to keep the span on left corner and the other text won't overlap it you can do something like this:

(without changing your markup:)

```css
div[name="comment"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font: medium -moz-fixed;
  font: -webkit-small-control;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: both;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative; /* added */
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
span {position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 0;}
```

```html
<div name="comment" contenteditable="true">
  <span class="bold" contenteditable="false">spantext</span>
</div>
```

Another solution can be using the `text-indent` property, but you need to change a little your markup:

```css
section {position: relative;}

div[name="comment"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font: medium -moz-fixed;
  font: -webkit-small-control;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%; 
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: both;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-indent: 80px; /* space for the first line and on every NEW LINE */
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
span {position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 0;}
```

```html
<section>
  <span class="bold" contenteditable="false">spantext</span>
  <div name="comment" contenteditable="true"></div>
</section>
```